# Bootstrap Modal is scrolling down on the smartphone device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the bootstrap modal, on the smartphone browser. It is scrolling down, and the modal doesn't appear.

On the debug browser(I use Chrome browser), when I choose the smartphone of the list, the modal is show corectly, but when I use the device, it doesn't work correctly. It is scrolling. 
I have read articles on stackoverflow regarding this issue, but in my case, it doesn't work.

I have made a printscreen: in this case the modal is shown corectly(on the chrome browser)

[image]

A part of code below:

```
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade' role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="padding-left:20px">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h2>@Facultate.Message.headStudentCurs</h2>
        </div>
        <div id='myModalContent'></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
 $(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and Header:

```
 <link href="~/Content/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>






<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title></title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

I want to remember that, i use the last bootstrap version v3.3.7

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source : [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

try like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. 
That was the issue:

```
.modal {
    padding-bottom: 600px;
    padding-left:40px !important;
    max-width:400px !important;
    position:fixed;

}
.bootbox{
     max-width:400px !important;
}

body.viewport-lg {

position: relative;
}
body {  
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
body.modal-open {

overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
}
```

I have deleted this code from the css file and i have changed the bootstrap version.